# WebSphere V 5.1.1 Installation Error

Tags: websphere

I am trying to install websphere 5.1.1 to window 7 , 64 bit operation. Even i can install properly,i can't do anything and it show me 'valid license is required to run websphere' . How shall i do? While i installed for window xp service pack 3, i didn't get such kind of errors.Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WASV5.x is not supported by IBM on windows7 OS . so i think it couldn't work.

Go through the supported OS details  of WAS , below link:

WebSphere Application Server V5.1.1 detailed system requirements
http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?rs=180&uid=swg27007344

Comment: Plus, WAS 5.x hasn't been supported at all since September 2008.